# Font error when trying to decrypt an encrypted .docx file

Tags: python, security, encryption, rsa

I'm working on a project that creates a framework for securing user's login information written in Python using RSA. When I tried to run the framework, everything went normal until it came to the decrypting phase. In the box where it displayed the options for letters' fonts. The preview text appeared to have error in font.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYDSy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImJLZ.png)

```py
def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def mod_inverse(a, m):
    if gcd(a, m) != 1:
        return None
    u1, u2, u3 = 1, 0, a
    v1, v2, v3 = 0, 1, m
    while v3 != 0:
        q = u3 // v3
        v1, v2, v3, u1, u2, u3 = u1 - q * v1, u2 - q * v2, u3 - q * v3, v1, v2, v3
    return u1 % m

def generate_keypair(p, q):
    n = p * q
    phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
    e = random.randrange(1, phi)
    g = gcd(e, phi)
    while g != 1:
        e = random.randrange(1, phi)
        g = gcd(e, phi)
    d = mod_inverse(e, phi)
    return (e, n), (d, n)

def encrypt(message, public_key):
    e, n = public_key
    cipher = [pow(ord(char), e, n) for char in message]
    return cipher

def decrypt(cipher, private_key):
    d, n = private_key
    message = [chr(pow(char, d, n)) for char in cipher]
    return ''.join(message)

def browse_file():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    file_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    file_entry.insert(tk.END, filepath)

def encrypt_file():
    p = 61
    q = 53
    public_key, _ = generate_keypair(p, q)
    filepath = file_entry.get()
    try:
        with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            plaintext = f.read()
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        with open(filepath, "r", encoding="latin-1") as f:  # Sử dụng mã hóa "latin-1" nếu gặp lỗi UnicodeDecodeError
            plaintext = f.read()
    encrypted_data = encrypt(plaintext, public_key)
    encrypted_filepath = filepath + ".encrypted"
    with open(encrypted_filepath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(' '.join(map(str, encrypted_data)))
    result_label.config(text="File encrypted successfully.")

def decrypt_file():
    p = 61
    q = 53
    _, private_key = generate_keypair(p, q)
    filepath = file_entry.get()
    
    try:
        with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:  # Sử dụng mã hóa utf-8
            encrypted_data = f.read().split()
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        result_label.config(text="Failed to open decrypted file: Invalid encoding (UTF-8)")
        return
    
    encrypted_data = list(map(int, encrypted_data))
    decrypted_data = decrypt(encrypted_data, private_key)
    
    # Create a decrypted file with a ".decrypted" extension
    decrypted_filepath = filepath[:-10]  # Remove ".encrypted" from the end of the file name
    decrypted_filepath += ".decrypted"
    
    # Convert decrypted data to bytes before writing (using utf-8 encoding)
    decrypted_data_bytes = bytes(decrypted_data, 'utf-8')
    
    try:
        with open(decrypted_filepath, "wb") as f:
            f.write(decrypted_data_bytes)
    except Exception as e:
        result_label.config(text="Failed to open decrypted file: " + str(e))
        return
    
    result_label.config(text="File decrypted successfully.")
    
    # Open the decrypted file
    try:
        with open(decrypted_filepath, "rb") as f:
            decrypted_data_bytes = f.read()
            # Now you can work with the decrypted_data_bytes as needed
    except Exception as e:
        result_label.config(text="Failed to open decrypted file: " + str(e))

browse_button = tk.Button(window, text="Browse", command=browse_file)
browse_button.place(x=290, y=120)

encrypt_button = tk.Button(window, text="Encrypt", command=encrypt_file)
encrypt_button.place(x=290, y=170)

decrypt_button = tk.Button(window, text="Decrypt", command=decrypt_file)
decrypt_button.place(x=290,y=220)

result_label = tk.Label(window, bg='#99CCFF')
result_label.place(x=240, y= 270)
```

Briefly on how to use this framework:

- hit "Browse"
- enter the Text bar and choose a XYZ.docx file
- hit "Encrypt" (it should appear "File encrypted successfully"
- hit "Browse" again
- There would be another XYZ.docx.encrypted file below the chosen .docx file, please choose it
- after choosing the file, hit "Decrypt"
- There would be another XYZ.docx.decrypted file below the chosen .docx file, please open it

I hope to find underlying mistakes and fix this issue so that the text can be normal after decrypting it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, here is few hints for you to get better answers: Make a minimal and reproducible code, you can remove the use of Tkinter and only provide the function of encrypt, decrypt and better to have the docx file. Secondly, trying to use English comment in your code for coding convention.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to attach a .docx file. However, any random .docx file would work

Comment: When working with encryption, you will need to work with binary (bytes), not Unicode strings. You'll need to fix that to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding of RSA use case which is not typical use for file encryption. The larger file, the larger encrypted file will be made. In this "learning case", I can show and correct you a simple base on your RSA implementation:

- You are trying to get the `uft-8`, but the encryption should work with bytes. Also trying to encode `latin-1` is not reasonable.
- You cannot generate private key on decryption process, the private key should be generated in encryption time and save different place in order to reuse in decryption
- The encryption process needed to be in order: get bytes of file -> encrypt to cipher integers -> turn integers into bytes -> save encrypted bytes & save private key
- The decryption process needed to be in order: get encrypted bytes & private key -> turn to cipher integers -> decrypt cipher integers to bytes -> concat bytes.

```
import random

PREVIEW_LENGTH = 15
BYTES_PADDING_SIZE = 2

def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def mod_inverse(a, m):
    if gcd(a, m) != 1:
        return None
    u1, u2, u3 = 1, 0, a
    v1, v2, v3 = 0, 1, m
    while v3 != 0:
        q = u3 // v3
        v1, v2, v3, u1, u2, u3 = u1 - q * v1, u2 - q * v2, u3 - q * v3, v1, v2, v3
    return u1 % m

def generate_keypair(p, q):
    n = p * q
    phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
    e = random.randrange(1, phi)
    g = gcd(e, phi)
    while g != 1:
        e = random.randrange(1, phi)
        g = gcd(e, phi)
    d = mod_inverse(e, phi)
    return (e, n), (d, n)

def encrypt(bytes, public_key):
    e, n = public_key
    print('Encrypting with public key', public_key)
    print('Origin bytes', bytes[:PREVIEW_LENGTH])
    # Encrypt each byte to an integer m^e mod n
    cipher_integers = [pow(byte, e, n) for byte in bytes]
    print('Cipher integers', cipher_integers[:PREVIEW_LENGTH])
    # Convert integers to bytes and concatenate them
    cipher_bytes = b''.join(int_to_bytes(char) for char in cipher_integers)
    print('Cipher bytes',cipher_bytes[:PREVIEW_LENGTH])
    return cipher_bytes

def decrypt(cipher_bytes, private_key):
    d, n = private_key
    print('Decrypting with private key', private_key)
    print('Cipher bytes', cipher_bytes[:PREVIEW_LENGTH])
    cipher_integers = [bytes_to_int(cipher_bytes[i:i + BYTES_PADDING_SIZE]) for i in range(0, len(cipher_bytes), BYTES_PADDING_SIZE)]
    print('Cipher integers', cipher_integers[:PREVIEW_LENGTH])
    decrypted_bytes = [pow(cipher_int, d, n) for cipher_int in cipher_integers]
    decrypted_bytes = bytes(decrypted_bytes)
    print('Origin bytes', decrypted_bytes[:PREVIEW_LENGTH])
    return decrypted_bytes

def int_to_bytes(n, padding=BYTES_PADDING_SIZE):
    # Convert an integer to its byte representation
    return n.to_bytes(padding, byteorder='big')

def bytes_to_int(b):
    # Convert bytes to integer
    return int.from_bytes(b, byteorder='big')

def key_to_pem(e, n, d):
    # Construct the PEM strings for public and private keys
    public_key_pem = f"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n{int_to_bytes(e).hex()}\n{int_to_bytes(n).hex()}\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
    private_key_pem = f"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n{int_to_bytes(n).hex()}\n{int_to_bytes(d).hex()}\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    return public_key_pem, private_key_pem

def pem_to_key(private_key_pem):
    # Remove PEM header and footer
    private_key_pem = private_key_pem.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "").strip()
    # Convert hex strings to integers
    n_hex, d_hex = private_key_pem.split('\n')
    n = bytes_to_int(bytes.fromhex(n_hex))
    d = bytes_to_int(bytes.fromhex(d_hex))
    return d, n

def encrypt_file(filepath):
    p = 61
    q = 53
    public_key, private_key = generate_keypair(p, q)

    with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
        bytes = f.read()
    
    encrypted_data = encrypt(bytes, public_key)
    encrypted_filepath = filepath + ".encrypted"

    with open(encrypted_filepath, "wb") as f:
        f.write(encrypted_data)

    print("File encrypted successfully.")

    _, private_key_pem = key_to_pem(public_key[0], public_key[1], private_key[0])
    return encrypted_filepath, private_key_pem

def decrypt_file(filepath, private_key_pem):
    private_key = pem_to_key(private_key_pem)

    with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
        encrypted_data = f.read()
    
    decrypted_data = decrypt(encrypted_data, private_key)
    
    # Create a decrypted file with a ".decrypted" extension
    decrypted_filepath = filepath.replace('.encrypted', '')  # Remove ".encrypted" from the end of the file name
    decrypted_filepath = 'decrypted_' + decrypted_filepath

    with open(decrypted_filepath, "wb") as f:
        f.write(decrypted_data)
    
    print("File decrypted successfully.")
    return decrypted_filepath


def main():
    sample_path = 'file-sample_1MB.docx'

    # Download sample for testing purpose, comment this if you already have a file
    # import requests
    # url = "https://file-examples.com/storage/fe805ba0cc65378da968c5c/2017/02/file-sample_1MB.docx"
    # response = requests.get(url)

    # if response.status_code != 200:
    #     raise Exception('Error')

    # with open(sample_path, "wb") as f:
    #     f.write(response.content)

    encrypt_path, private_key_pem = encrypt_file(sample_path)
    decrypt_path = decrypt_file(encrypt_path, private_key_pem)

main()
```

Now you can see the result:

```
Encrypting with public key (1613, 3233)
Origin bytes b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00\xa6c\x10K\x00'
Cipher integers [2730, 658, 3077, 2601, 497, 0, 220, 220, 220, 0, 2869, 2590, 1765, 658, 0]
Cipher bytes b'\n\xaa\x02\x92\x0c\x05\n)\x01\xf1\x00\x00\x00\xdc\x00'
File encrypted successfully.
Decrypting with private key (677, 3233)
Cipher bytes b'\n\xaa\x02\x92\x0c\x05\n)\x01\xf1\x00\x00\x00\xdc\x00'
Cipher integers [2730, 658, 3077, 2601, 497, 0, 220, 220, 220, 0, 2869, 2590, 1765, 658, 0]
Origin bytes b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00\xa6c\x10K\x00'
File decrypted successfully.
```

But the problem is, the 1MB file encrypted to 2.1MB (2x times) and very slow even the RSA key is very simple number, so that's why we should not use RSA. Instead, AES is the way to go, you can also combine RSA to AES key for more secure but I will not make things complicated.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
import os

PREVIEW_LENGTH = 15

def encrypt(bytes, aes_key, iv):
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(aes_key), modes.CFB(iv), backend=default_backend())

    # Encrypt the large file with AES
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    cipher_bytes = encryptor.update(bytes) + encryptor.finalize()

    print('Encrypting with aes_key', aes_key)
    print('Origin bytes', bytes[:PREVIEW_LENGTH])
    print('Cipher bytes', cipher_bytes[:PREVIEW_LENGTH])
    return cipher_bytes

def decrypt(cipher_bytes, aes_key, iv):
    # Create an AES cipher object with the AES key and IV
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(aes_key), modes.CFB(iv), backend=default_backend())

    # Decrypt the encrypted file with AES
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    decrypted_bytes = decryptor.update(cipher_bytes) + decryptor.finalize()

    print('Decrypting with aes key', aes_key)
    print('Cipher bytes', cipher_bytes[:PREVIEW_LENGTH])
    print('Origin bytes', decrypted_bytes[:PREVIEW_LENGTH])
    return decrypted_bytes

def generate_key():
    # Generate a random 256-bit AES key
    aes_key = os.urandom(32)
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    return aes_key, iv

def encrypt_file(filepath):
    aes_key, iv = generate_key()

    with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
        bytes = f.read()
    
    encrypted_data = encrypt(bytes, aes_key, iv)
    encrypted_filepath = filepath + ".encrypted"

    with open(encrypted_filepath, "wb") as f:
        f.write(encrypted_data)

    print("File encrypted successfully.")
    return encrypted_filepath, aes_key, iv

def decrypt_file(filepath, aes_key, iv):
    with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
        encrypted_data = f.read()
    
    decrypted_data = decrypt(encrypted_data, aes_key, iv)
    
    # Create a decrypted file with a ".decrypted" extension
    decrypted_filepath = filepath.replace('.encrypted', '')  # Remove ".encrypted" from the end of the file name
    decrypted_filepath = 'decrypted_' + decrypted_filepath

    with open(decrypted_filepath, "wb") as f:
        f.write(decrypted_data)
    
    print("File decrypted successfully.")
    return decrypted_filepath


def main():
    sample_path = 'file-sample_1MB.docx'

    # Download sample for testing purpose, comment this if you already have a file
    # import requests
    # url = "https://file-examples.com/storage/fe805ba0cc65378da968c5c/2017/02/file-sample_1MB.docx"
    # response = requests.get(url)

    # if response.status_code != 200:
    #     raise Exception('Error')

    # with open(sample_path, "wb") as f:
    #     f.write(response.content)

    encrypt_path, aes_key, iv = encrypt_file(sample_path)
    decrypt_path = decrypt_file(encrypt_path, aes_key, iv)

main()
```

Result is fast, simple:

```
Encrypting with aes_key b"\xe1\xea\xbc~tP\xab\x00\\'Uf\xe8\x87|\xdd\xa0\x965\x0e\x88\n\xb3\xb4\xb8\xb4\r\xde\x00c\x0e\xf9"
Origin bytes b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00\xa6c\x10K\x00'
Cipher bytes b'G\xb9B\xdeK\xedG\x9a\xcd_-\x9ebl\x07'
File encrypted successfully.
Decrypting with aes key b"\xe1\xea\xbc~tP\xab\x00\\'Uf\xe8\x87|\xdd\xa0\x965\x0e\x88\n\xb3\xb4\xb8\xb4\r\xde\x00c\x0e\xf9"
Cipher bytes b'G\xb9B\xdeK\xedG\x9a\xcd_-\x9ebl\x07'
Origin bytes b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00\xa6c\x10K\x00'
File decrypted successfully.
```